# Definitions of Flat Connections

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, tangent-bundle

I have some questions about the definitions of flat connections, and want to make sure if my understanding is correct.

In Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, two definitions of flatness for connections are given:

> (Definition 4.1.5) The curvature of a connection $D$ on the vector bundle $E$ is the operator $$F = D \circ D: \Omega^0(E) \to \Omega^2(E)$$
> The connection is called flat, if its curvature satisfies $F=0$.

For a connection on the tangent bundle $TM$,

> (Definition 4.1.8) A connection $\nabla$ on $TM$ is flat if each point in $M$ possesses
> a neighborhood $U$ with local coordinates for which all the coordinate vector fields
> $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$ are parallel, that is, $$\nabla \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} = 0$$

Later, it shows that

> (Theorem 4.1.3) A connection $\nabla$ on $TM$ is flat if and only if its curvature and torsion
> vanish identically.

In definition 4.1.5, if we take $E = TM$, then the flatness just means vanishing curvature. Therefore, if a connection on $TM$ is flat in the sense of definition 4.1.8, then by theorem 4.1.3, it is also flat in the sense of definition 4.1.5.

I am wondering whether the converse is also true? Or is there any example where the connection has vanishing curvature but nontrivial torsion?

I also saw in Tu's *Differential Geometry* that the concept of torsion does not make sense for a connection on an arbitrary vector bundle. I suppose this is the reason why we merely require vanishing curvature for flat connections on an arbitrary vector bundle. Therefore, we have two (possibly) different definitions for flat connections on $TM$.

Comment: You can find this discussed several places on this site. If you take a Lie group with a left-invariant metric and declare the left-invariant vector fields to be parallel, then the connection forms vanish and all the structure is in the torsion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curvature and torsion are both ‘obstructions to integrability’, but in slightly different senses, and so as mentioned in the comment, the two definitions are not equivalent. The correct theorems, which I think will clarify things for you, are the following:

> **Theorem 1. (Curvature is obstruction to existence of local parallel frames)**
>
> Let $E$ be a (rank $k$) vector bundle (over an $n$-dimensional base $M$) with a connection $D$. Then, the curvature $F$ vanishes if and only if about each point of the base manifold there is a smooth local frame of parallel sections of $E$ (i.e there exist smooth local sections $\{e_1,\dots, e_k\}$ which satisfy $De_i=0$ identically).

One direction is easy, because $F(\cdot,\cdot)\cdot e_i=D(De_i)=0$. For the converse, one way to prove it is to first establish that vanishing curvature implies that locally, parallel-transport is path-independent. Then, you fix a point $p$ in the base manifold, a basis $\{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$ of the fiber $E_p$, and then parallel-transport it all over (well-defined due to path-independence) a small neighborhood of $p$ to get local sections $\{e_1,\dots, e_k\}$; these sections are smooth by ODE regularity theory. By construction, these guys are parallel with respect to $D$.

Now, you can specialize to $TM$, and the above statement is of course still true. A natural question one might ask in the case of $E=TM$ is under what conditions one may take the local parallel sections $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ of $TM$ (guaranteed to exist by the previous theorem) to be those arising from some coordinates: $e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$? Well, this happens if and only if the $e_i$’s Lie-commute with each other: $[e_i,e_j]=0$ for all $i,j$. Now, the torsion $T$ is equal to
\begin{align}
T(e_i,e_j)=\nabla_{e_i}e_j-\nabla_{e_j}e_i-[e_i,e_j]=0-0-[e_i,e_j],
\end{align}
where the $0$’s are due to being parallel sections. So, we see that the $e_i$’s come from some coordinates $x^i$ if and only if they Lie-commute, which happens if and only if the torsion vanishes. Thus,

> **Theorem 2. (Curvature and torsion are obstruction to existence of local parallel coordinate frames)**
>
> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $D$ a connection on $TM$. Then, the curvature and torsion vanish if and only if about each point of $M$ there is a local coordinate chart $(U,x)$ such that the vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ are parallel with respect to $D$.

So, curvature (on any vector bundle) obstructs the existence of parallel frames, while torsion (in the case of $TM$) is the further obstruction to making them coordinate frames.

As a further corollary of theorem $2$, we can see that in the case of a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, with the Levi-Civita connection (torsion free by definition) there exists an ‘orthonormal’ system of coordinates if and only if the curvature vanishes. This is the so-called ‘fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry’ (which Spivak proves like 5 different ways in Vol II of his Differential geometry books).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It really clarified the notion and idea for me.